# Stopping beep sound of google speech recognizer

Tags: android, speech

I am using the default speech recognizer of Android. But you may know that it plays a beep sound when starting the recognizer and when the onError() event is fired. Beep sound is played from Android version 5.x.

My requirement is to implement continuous recognizer. So I have to start this recognizer again and again. In this situation beep sound is being played again and again. I have tried to have some solution like below:

Mute the media sound before starting recognizer and unmute again onSpeechReady() event. On the other hand, if recognizer do not detect any speech for 4/5 sec then it automatically calls onError() event and this onError() event plays the beep again. To resolve this, I have stopped the recognizer forcefully after 3 sec and called onError() by a timer before system calls this onError() event. 
But as I closed the recognizer forcefully, system is getting an exception here and playing a buzz.

Anybody can give any solution on how I can stop this beep sound as well as the buzz.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code before starting your speech

```
AudioManager amanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true);
amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, true);
amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, true);
amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
```

Use the following code after getting result

```
AudioManager amanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, false);
amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, false);
amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, false);
amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
```